# Targeting Dynamic ID's in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic

I am creating a dynamic ID inside an li element and I want to target each ID so I can animate the opacity.  I set up a variable "_Btn" to console log the value of each id which returns the correct id names but when I try to target the ID in jquery it does not animate the opacity.  What am I doing wrong how do I target each ID in jquery?

```
var btnInfo = [{
  img: 'images/thumbs/motionGraphicsThumb1.jpg',
  id: 'btn1',
  title: 'TITLE1',
  url: 'folio/pg1.html'
}, {
  img: 'images/thumbs/motionGraphicsThumb2.jpg',
  id: 'btn2',
  title: 'TITLE2',
  url: 'folio/pg2.html'
}, {
  img: 'images/thumbs/motionGraphicsThumb3.jpg',
  id: 'btn3',
  title: 'TITLE3',
  url: 'folio/pg3.html'
}]
for (var i = 0; i < btnInfo.length; i++) {

  $('.thumbWrapper .container ul').append('<li class="hideThumbs" id="' + btnInfo[i].id + ' "  onclick="contentLoader(\'' + btnInfo[i].url + '\')"><div class="view view-tenth"><img src="' + btnInfo[i].img + '"><div class="mask"><h2>' + btnInfo[i].title + '</h2></div></div></li>');

  var _btn = btnInfo[i].id;
  console.log("BTN ID " + _btn);

  $("#" + _btn).animate({
    opacity: 100
  });
}
}
```

Comment: Give us some sample `id` values? Can't you use `.hideThumbs`?

Comment: There's an extra `}` at the bottom. Kindly check.

Comment: The class "hideThumbs" sets the thumbs to have an opacity of zero. So I want to animate each ID's opacity to 1.  .hideThumbs{
 opacity: 0;
}

Comment: I have a native JS solution for this if you like.
http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/gPggLB
Click on the spain button and then on close, the div is also dynamicaly created.
In your code, that event handler line is...not very beautiful:-)
Better assign a class to the btn elements, jQuery is made for stuff like that.
Show th efull code, I wanna try:-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you create `<li>`s as not visible, then want to use `animate()` to make them visible smoothly.
So more likely your `hideThumbs` class is set to `display: none;`: this way, change `opacity` has no effect, and the element keeps invisible.

Instead your CSS should be:

```
.hideThumbs {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Apart from the above, note that:

- `opacity: 100` has no sense (though it'll work); values are between 0 (invisible) and 1 (fully visible).
- you'd better write your `var _btn = btnInfo[i].id;` before the `<li>` creation, so you can use `btn` rather `btnInfo[i].id` inside of it.

Comment: Yes the class .hideThumbs does have opacity set to 0. and I am trying to animate the opacity to 1 targeting the dynamic ID's but I can't seem get  that working. I changed the opacity in my jQuery from 100 to 1 and it still does not work.

Comment: @FrankDTankDeLeon Ok but are you sure there is nothing equivalent to `display:none;` in this `hideThumbs` class, or in the `view` and `view-tenth` ones?